# Hiberate (5.4.27.Final) schema export utility generates unordered script leading to Integrity constraint violation exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using the hibernate schema export utility to generate schema script from entities information present in hibernate mapping XML as below:

```
 Metadata metadata = = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
                    .addDirectory(new File(hbmLocation))
                    .buildMetadata();

 new SchemaExport()
                    .setFormat(true)
                    .setDelimiter(";")
                    .setOutputFile(outputFile)
                    .createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), metadata);
```

This generates valid SQL script but there is an issue with the order of the statements in the script

e.g.

1. INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE (ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (3, 8);
2. INSERT INTO permissions (id, name) VALUES (8, 'update');

The order of occurrence in the script should have been reverse! And this results in a error because the foreign key with id 8 is not yet inserted when the first statement executes

leading to:

```
[Code: -177, SQL State: 23503]  integrity constraint violation: 
foreign key no parent; PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE_PERM_FK table: PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE value: 8
```

statements used to create the relationships are as below

```
create table PERMISSIONS ( ID bigint not null, NAME varchar(255), primary key (ID) );

create table PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE ( ROLE_ID bigint not null, PERMISSION_ID bigint not null, primary key (ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID) );

alter table PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE add constraint permissions_for_role_perm_fk foreign key (PERMISSION_ID) references PERMISSIONS;
```

I am unable to create a minimal example where the issue can be reproduced. The schema where the issue happens has about 100 tables.

Is there any guarantee that hibernate takes care of ordering the script generated ? or does the schema export tool need some manual changes ? any thoughts would be appreciated.

version of hibernate used is 5.4.27.Final.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but for DDL Hibernate first generates all create statements for tables and only then the create statements for constraints. Any insert statement you are seeing probably comes from a sql file you defined.